# How to let Mathematica return impulse or Dirac delta functions when computing integrals?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

For example, let's say I want to compute the (continuous-time) Fourier transform of the signal/function $\cos{(3t)}$, which is given by the following improper integral:

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos{(3t)} e^{-j\omega t} \, \mathrm{dt} \tag 1$

whose value is:

$\pi \, \delta{(\omega - 3)} + \pi \, \delta{(\omega + 3)} \tag 2$

The corresponding Mathematica code to compute the integral of *(1)* would be `Integrate[Cos[3*t]*Exp[-I*w*t], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {w \[Element] Reals}]`. However, after executing such code Mathematica returns the message "Integrate: Integral of $e^{-i t w} \text{Cos}{[3 t]}$ does not converge on {$-\infty$,$\infty$}." How can I tell Mathematica to use the impulse/Dirac delta function during the computation of the integral, in order to return *(2)* or something similar?

Comment: Use FourierTransform instead, e.g., `FourierTransform[Cos[3 t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]`.

Comment: It should be noticed that `FourierTransform[Cos[3 t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]`  is not an proper divergent integral, but uses another definition (e.g. see [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) or/and [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fourier_transform_of_a_generalized_function)). I think this is impemented in Mathematica as a table value.

Comment: Workaround: `InverseFourierTransform[
 Integrate[
  FourierTransform[Cos[3*t] Exp[-I \[Omega] t], \[Omega], s], {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> s \[Element] Reals], s, \[Omega]]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use Dirac or Heaviside functions explicitly in your expression, *Mathematica* figures out that you're working with generalized functions. Unfortunately, it doesn't always work the other way: *Mathematica* won't volunteer to use generalized functions unless you're explicitly using Fourier/Laplace transforms. So, if you're working with Fourier integrals, and want results in terms of generalized functions, you need to use `FourierTransform` rather than `Integrate`.

Comment: Hi John (remember me?) This is a nice example of an integral the type you were describing in our recent conversation. One can integrate over a large symmetric range and get a pair of sincs. Taking the limit as the range ->infinity gives deltas. That said, `Limit` will not recognize this (`Limit` has its limits). But this manner of integration does involve a regularization insofar as we in effect take a principle value integral. PS I upvoted this.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau ツ