# Obtaining Inverse Fourier Transforms by "FourierTransform" vs. "Integrate" Option

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to calculate the inverse Fourier transform of "1" using two approaches. One using the Integrate option and the other with InverseFourierTransform, so the function looks like the following, with "w" as the frequency.

```
Integrate[1*Exp[I w t], {w, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {Element[w, Reals], Element[t, Reals]}]
```

The integral does not converge in this range from -infinity to +infinity. If we use `{{w, -1, 1}`, then we get sinc function 2sin(t)/t.

And,

```
InverseFourierTransform [1, w, t]
```

Gives the desired delta function `Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] DiracDelta[t]`

Is there a way to obtain Dirac Delta as an answer with the Integrate option?

Comment: Unlikely. `(Inverse)FourierTransform` is designed to compute the continuation of the (inverse) fourier transform of quite general distributions. `Integrate` is supposed to work only for (improperly) integrable functions... somewhat by definition. And `w |-> 1*Exp[I w t]` is just not improperly integrable.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I believe you mean 'properly'.

Comment: Nah, I did mean "improperly integrable". ˋSincˋ is improperly integrable, but neither Riemannian nor Lebesgue integrable. And ˋIntegrateˋ should handle it well.

Comment: That was asked and answered a lot times at this forum. The improper integral `Integrate[1*Exp[I w t], {w, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {Element[w, Reals], Element[t, Reals]}]` diverges, but the Fourier transform of `1` is defined  in another way (e.g. see the "Tempered distibution" section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) and [that article](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fourier_transform_of_a_generalized_function)).

Comment: See a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262741/how-to-let-mathematica-return-impulse-or-dirac-delta-functions-when-computing-in/262742#262742).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-rigorous way to do it using the claim that $\frac1{2\varepsilon}\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon}f(t-a)dt$ converges to $f(a)$.  I haven't justified swapping the integrals, but we should have

$$\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iw(t-a)}dwdt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon e^{iw(t-a)}dtdw$$
Now the best I can do is to get it to work in cases

```
Integrate[Exp[I ω(t-a)],{ω,-∞,∞},{t,-ε,ε},Assumptions->{Element[ω|t|a,Reals]}]
Integrate[Exp[I ω t]   ,{ω,-∞,∞},{t,-ε,ε},Assumptions->{Element[ω|t  ,Reals]}]
```

Strangely, if you include the assumption that `ε` is real in the `Integrate`, it will produce horrible answers.  Anyway, the results of those integrals are

```
ConditionalExpression[0, ε^2/a^2 < 1]
(2π ε)/Sqrt[ε^2]
```

so you can evaluate these limits right after the `Integrate`s

```
Limit[%%/(2ε), ε->0, Direction->"FromAbove"]
Limit[% /(2ε), ε->0, Direction->"FromAbove"]
```

to find

```
ConditionalExpression[0, a != 0]
∞
```

Not as satisfying as the `DiracDelta` symbol, but something.  I find it odd that the `ConditionalExpression` doesn't also capture the case when `a=0`, usually it works pretty slick like that.